# what is the recommended method of renaming columns starting with a certain string in dplyr 1.0.2?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble

```
xx <- structure(list(Abundance.126 = c(22.3, 24.5), Abundance.127N = c(23.4, 
22.7), Abundance.127C = c(16.6, 21.2), Abundance.128N = c(19.6, 
22.8), Abundance.128C = c(23.2, 25.9), Abundance.129N = c(22.7, 
25.6), Abundance.129C = c(20.7, 35.2), Abundance.130N = c(17, 
33.9), Abundance.130C = c(18.1, 25.8), Abundance.131N = c(20.3, 
28.9), Abundance.131C = c(18.8, 31.2), Abundance.132N = c(17.1, 
36.8), Abundance.132C = c(19, 41.5), Abundance.133N = c(19.2, 
35.3), Abundance.133C = c(21.7, 43.9), Abundance.134N = c(19.6, 
53.2)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to rename columns starting with the string "Abundance" (I have many other columns, but I removed them to make the post shorter). I could use

```
rename_at(xx, vars(contains('Abundance.')), ~(sub('Abundance.', '', .)))
```

but, reading about vars(), I get:

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/vars.html

vars() was only needed for the scoped verbs, which have been superseded by the use of across() in an existing verb.

do I understand correctly that vars() should not be used anymore?

Answer (score 1):

`rename_at`/`rename_if`/`rename_all` have superseded by `rename_with`. So in the new `dplyr` you can rename the column as :

```
library(dplyr)
xx %>% rename_with(~sub('Abundance.', '', .), contains('Abundance'))

#   126 127N 127C 128N 128C 129N 129C 130N 130C 131N 131C 132N 132C 133N 133C 134N
#1 22.3 23.4 16.6 19.6 23.2 22.7 20.7 17.0 18.1 20.3 18.8 17.1 19.0 19.2 21.7 19.6
#2 24.5 22.7 21.2 22.8 25.9 25.6 35.2 33.9 25.8 28.9 31.2 36.8 41.5 35.3 43.9 53.2
```

and yes, `vars()` is not needed anymore.